# Programs compatible with Raspberry Pi 3 but not with Pi Zero?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspberry-pi-zero

I am trying to control an epaper display with a raspberry pi zero. I am following this great tutorial: https://beenje.github.io/blog/posts/my-lego-macintosh-classic-with-raspberry-pi-and-e-paper-display/ He did work with a Pi Zero as well.

I got the ansible playbook running which would get me a clock on the display. But the display does not change. If I'm ejecting the SD card and putting it into a Pi 3 that I got at home, the clock is running perfectly on the epaper display.

Because I thought that something is wrong with the pins of my pi zero, I ordered a new Pi. But it's all the same. I've used different power supplies as well. To change the power supply port of the Pi Zero hasn't helped either.

When I tried a different approach over a docker container that's deployed in the cloud (resin.io) the display has changed. Everything worked.

How is it possible that all the same software is running perfectly on a Pi 3 and on a Pi Zero, it is not working.
Especially since it is working for Benjamin - the author of the tutorial I'm following.

I am on Raspbian Stretch because Benjamin has used it, too.

Edit: I'm using a Pi Zero with presoldered header

Thank you!

Comment: did you see remark: *Note that commit 282e88f in embeddedartists/gratis repository added support for the RaspberryPi 3, but broke the PI Zero W. You currently have to use the commit 9b7accc68 if you have a PI Zero W.* ?

Comment: Yeah, this was added when I commented his post, that it's not working. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, that the repository of Embedded Artists for the ePaper Display did break support for Pi Zero W as it added support for Pi 3 with the commit 282e88f.

Currently, if you want to use the repository on the Pi zero you have to use commit 9b7accc68,